# Changing the date format in SharePoint 2010

Tags: regional-settings, date-format

The date format in my SharePoint 2010 Farm is set to the US format (mm-dd-yyyy).
I need to make a global change so that the displayed date is in the format dd-mm-yyyy for all documents.

Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

I know that I can go into the Site Settings for each site and change the Regional Settings > Locale. But I need to make this change over the entire farm.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change it at farm level. Instead, you can create a calculated field for original date field and format the date accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has posted a similar question before on here. They were given this bit of powershell to iterate through the Site Collections in the farm and change the settings to the UK region:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Globalization") | out-null
get-spweb -site http://yoururl -limit all |% {
    $_.Locale = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo(2057);
    $_.Update()
}
#see if things applied
get-spweb -site http://yoururl -limit all |% {
    $_.Locale
}
```

Could you use something like this? The original answer is here:
[Change locale for all site collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/change-locale-for-all-site-collections)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to change the locale for all mysite hosts via Powershell?

Comment: is it possible to change the date settings to dd-MMM-YYYY ?